# Can Hom(X,Y) be given a natural scheme structure?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X$ and $Y$ be $S$-schemes. Is there a "natural" scheme structure on $\operatorname{Hom}_S(X,Y)$, maybe subject to some conditions on the schemes in question? Interpret "natural" however you'd like.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/248309/3217

Comment: $\mathrm{Hom}_S (X, Y)$ is not even a topological space. A better question would be to ask whether a certain presheaf is representable – see the linked question.