# When is the base change functor fully faithful

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

For a field extension $L/k$, there is a base change functor $\textbf{Sch}/k \rightarrow \textbf{Sch}/L$. The answer to the MO question [Why is the base change functor faithful](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133955/why-is-the-base-change-functor-faithful) has shown that this functor is always faithful.

**Question 1**: Is this functor always full? If not, could anyone provide a counter-example?

**Question 2**: If $L/k$ is a finite separable extension, in this nice case, is the base change functor fully faithful?

Comment: Asking that the functor is fully faithful is same as asking that the $L-$ points of the scheme $Hom_k (X,Y)$ are the same as $k-$points. This is usually not the case.

Comment: @random123 Could you explain this more carefully, what's the scheme $Hom_k(X,Y)$?

Comment: Have you tried some really simple examples, like $Hom_k(\operatorname{Spec}k,\mathbb{A}^1_k)\to Hom_L(\operatorname{Spec}L,\mathbb{A}^1_L)$ ?

Comment: A definition could be found here : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/248309/172843

Comment: @random123: Expressing things in terms of the "$Hom$-functor" doesn't help much since it is not a scheme in general.